# Angular - $scope.myForm.$setPristine() is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Form is not cleared after saved record in angularJs. I'm trying to reset form many ways, but form is not reset.
My angularjs version is 1.4.8.
This question is also a duplicate, but I tried what stack overflow users said. That has not worked for me.

Looking for a positive reply

Thank you.

**Html code:**

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" novalidate>

    <input type="hidden" name="forumValue" ng-model="fid.forumValue"
    id="forumValue" placeholder="fourm Id" />

    <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputAnswer" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Answer</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <textarea rows="10" name="answer" class="form-control"
    ng-model="fid.answer" required></textarea>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
    ng-click="saveUserAnswer(fid)">Post Your Answer</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
$scope.saveUserAnswer = function(fid) {
UserRepository.saveUserAnswer(fid).then(
function(response) {
var status = response.message;
if (status == "success") {
    alert("posted success");
    $scope.UserAnswer=getUserOnIdAnswer(fid.UserValue);
    $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.myForm.$setUntouched();
    $state.go('UserAnswer');

}
else {
    $scope.User=response;
    alert("posted Fail,Please correct the details..!!");
    }
});

};
```

Comment: Perhaps this will work if you change the form name to `form.myForm` and also declare a variable on your scope like so `$scope.form = {}` refactor your code with the above changes hopefully that should work .

Comment: @lacoder i tried but this is also not working.

Comment: It also looks like your function name in the html and the script file don't match `saveForumAnswer()` or is it `saveUserAnswer()`

Comment: @lacoder saveUserAnswer() only I typed wrongly both should be same

Answer (score 0):

Is your form wrapped in an `ng-if` statement? If so, the form might be inside a child scope, and you might try:

**Option A**
Replace your `ng-if` with an `ng-hide`.

**Option B**
Bind the form to an existing object on the parent scope:

```
$scope.myData = {};
$scope.saveUserAnswer = function(fid) {
  ...
};
```

Then in your HTML, refer to the form on the parent scope:

```
<form name="myData.myForm" id="myForm" novalidate>
</form>
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15615

Comment: Other directives, such as `ng-repeat`, also create child scopes, so it's not just `ng-if`.

Comment: Two sides of the same coin, I think. You're probably right that `ng-show` would be a more direct replacement.

Comment: @ColinHemphill my html page contains both ng-repeat and ng-hide. but i'm using these two are outside form

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted to recreate your problem but without the call to the UserRepository just to confirm that we can set the form $pristine value to true and to reset the form.

```
  <form name="form.myForm" id="myForm" novalidate>
                     <input type="hidden" name="forumValue" ng-model="fid.forumValue" id="forumValue" placeholder="fourm Id" />

                  <div class="form-grou`enter code here`p row">
                    <label for="inputAnswer" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Answer</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <textarea rows="10" name="form.myForm.answer" class="form-control" ng-model="fid.answer" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="saveUserAnswer(fid)">Post Your Answer</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
   </form>
                <pre>{{form.myForm.$pristine}}</pre>
```

and the controller code like so :

```
      $scope.form = {};
      $scope.saveUserAnswer = function(fid) {
        $scope.form.myForm.$setPristine();
        $scope.fid = {};
//omitted the user repository code
      };
```

The above will set the pristine value of the form to `true` and also reset the value of `fid` on click of the button.

**EDIT**

Also the call to your repository function should be in this format:

```
 UserRepository.saveUserAnswer(fid).then(
 function(response){
//success
},
function(response){
//error 
    }
);
```

Comment: First time form reseting working fine.second time onwards hidden value is not bind to controller

Comment: can you give us a plunk or something to look at ?

Comment: Form contains two values one is forumValue this is hidden filed.another one is answer.after form reseting next time onwards forumValue is null. only answer is binded to controller.

Answer (score 0):

In controller try to add '$scope.fid.answer=null;' after                                        scope.myForm.$setPristine();

like this.

```
$scope.saveUserAnswer = function(fid) {
    UserRepository.saveUserAnswer(fid).then(
    function(response) {
    var status = response.message;
    if (status == "success") {
    alert("posted success");
    $scope.UserAnswer=getUserOnIdAnswer(fid.UserValue);
    $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.myForm.$setUntouched();
    $scope.fid.answer=null;
    $state.go('UserAnswer');

}
else {
    $scope.User=response;
    alert("posted Fail,Please correct the details..!!");
    }
});

};
```